# image popsup and then goes directly open without lightbox

Tags: lightbox2

when clicking on image set it pops out and goes directly open without the use of lightbox. When I go page back then the lightbox start working normally.

when I change

```
  <a href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="1"><img class="" src="images/import/import1/1.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="images/import/import1/1.jpg" data-lightbox="1"></a>
  <a href="images/import/import1/2.jpg" data-lightbox="1"></a>
```

Comment: did you get any error at the first time? I am suspecting maybe a script was not ready when you clicked

Comment: No errors. it feels like the original image link is activating the script and make it works.

Comment: I don’t know if its common to send a link of the desire webpage. If yes, please tell me. that should clarify what’s happening

Comment: yes, if you have the link, then send that it is better to see what does not work actually

Comment: under the white Ferrari there are the links called Images#1. So please scroll down. https://bullevard.com/import.html

Comment: you are having another code that listen on a tag click and it affect to light box. the event listener is     $("a").click(function(n) { var a = n.currentTarget.getAttribute("href"); you need to change that to not attach on a tag in light box

Comment: search $("a").click in your javascript code instead. I dont think it comes from lightbox

Comment: I am still unable to get lightbox to work correctly. Anyone? help? bullevard.com/import.html

Comment: did you find out the one I mentioned? it has this in click event  /firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && setTimeout(function() {

Comment: do I need to look in scrip.js?

Comment: I see a few setTimeout(function() {

Comment: I dont know, just look all possible scripts in your project. since the script on your site was minimized so it is hard to tell where it is from

Comment: Not exactly the same line you mention

Comment: I had a nother script.js from other template to try. lightbox worked but the template layout was totaly messed.

Comment: if it is not sensitive, you can send me link to your project then I can help.

Comment: I can email rar with the project inside.

Comment: thank you. Send it allready. It is regarding import.html